# How to require a folder?

Tags: lua, lib, luajit

im new to lua and luajit, making a mod for stalker, that will send http request to shocker, when getting damage ingame
found this library:
https://github.com/LPGhatguy/luajit-request
trying to require this library like in github's example by require("luajit-request"), that doesn't work.

Comment: What is your `package.path`? If you can't check, drop us the error message if available, it should contain all directories checked for module. Is the _inner_ (one with init.lua file) luajit-request located in one of the directories in your package path?